# django: annotate on groups then join back (as pandas groupby + transform)

Tags: python, django, pandas, orm, annotate

In a django setting, given a table with columns

```
`id`,`x`,`y`,`z`
```

I need to

- `groupby` on `y`
- find the maximum value of `z` in each group
- join the outcomes back such that I end up with a table reading

  `id`,`x`,`y`,`z`,`max_z`

I managed to get the group maxima via

```
 max_z = table.objects.values('y').annotate(max_z = Max('z'))
```

However, I am struggling in the "join back" operation.
If I traverse the new query as

```
 max_z.values('id','x','y','z','max_z')
```

then the column `max_z` and `z` read equal. i.e.

```
 `max_z == z` for each `id`
```

thus `max_z` does not represent anymore the max value for each group.

---

For instance, in pandas background, the operation here would read

```
 df['max_z'] = df.groupby('y').z.transform('max')
```

---

Any help appreciated

Comment: Do you need the `max_z` against each id?

Comment: I just recreated an example and ran exactly what you have written and got what I think you wanted.   The question is, what are you observing that indicates a problem?  An error?  Unexpected results?  Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @AKS, I do need the `max_z` against each id

Comment: @piRSquared, in my case ` max_z.values('id','x','y','z','max_z')` does not contain the maxima against each `id`, rather `z==max_z`, which then is not the maximum..

Comment: @Acorbe see my answer and help me see understand what you need.

Comment: @piRSquared.. Thanks. I need to solve the problem in django, though. I put pandas code to try to frame my question the best